# nightwatch custom command prototype

Tags: node.js, prototype, nightwatch.js

I followed the instruction from [here](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/blob/master/lib/api/client-commands/pause.js#L22) (pause command in nightwatch), in order to create a custom command which gets the current used selector (css or xpath).

```
var util = require('util');
var events = require('events');

function GetSelector() {
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);
}

util.inherits(GetSelector, events.EventEmitter);

GetSelector.prototype.command = function (callback) {
    callback(this.client.locateStrategy);
};

module.exports = GetSelector;
```

The implementation gets the current selector, although the program stuck when the custom command is called.

```
  browser
    .getSelector(function (currentSelector) { 
      console.log('getSelector: ' + currentSelector); 
    })
```

I have also tried to wrap around with "self.perform" as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286964/nightwatch-custom-command-callback), unfortunatelly without any luck.

```
GetSelector.prototype.command = function (browser, callback) {
    browser.perform(function () {
        callback(this.client.locateStrategy);
    })
};
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Signaling the complete event needs to be done inside an asynchronous action" `action"self.emit('complete');`, according to the Nightwatch [homepage](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide/).

```
GetSelector.prototype.command = function (cb) {
    var self = this;

    process.nextTick(function () {
        cb(self.client.locateStrategy);

        //Signaling the complete event needs to be done inside an asynchronous action.
        self.emit('complete');
    });

    return this;
};
```

process.nextTick makes sure that the `self.emit('complete');` will be called by the next tick of the event loop which are processed by Node.